# auto-pst-pdf package in combination with textpos and chemmacros

Tags: chemmacros, auto-pst-pdf, textpos

I seem to have problems with the auto-pst-pdf package, chemmacros package and the textpos package.

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
%\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{29mm}(45mm,80mm)
    Some random text.
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

If i comment out the package chemmacros, my random text is displayed correctly. If I activate the chemmacros package, my text completely disappears as I implemented it into the textblock.
If the auto-pst-pdf package is not used at all, this problem does not occur.

I do not know, why this happens, but I really need all three packages for my thesis. I use Texmaker 5.0.3 on a MacBook running macOS Catalina. Similar problem occurs with TeXShop Version 4.44.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce that on my system with the most recent version of all involved packages. Which version of the packages did you use?

Comment: @leandriis Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c,
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j, 
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a, 
Package: chemmacros 2017/08/28 v5.8b, 
Package: auto-pst-pdf 2009/04/26 v0.,
Package: textpos 2019/04/15 v1.9.1
Does this help? I copied these information from the log file

Comment: I definitely suggest updating your pagages. I have a significantly newer version of graphicx 2019/11/30 and chemmacros 2020/03/07 v5.1. With these versions I can't reproduce teh issue you describe.

Comment: @leandriis I have now updated all packages, using the same versions of graphicx and chemmacros as you do, but this problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This *might* be a known problem, which may be fixed.  See the [textpos issue](https://bitbucket.org/nxg/textpos/issues/7/bad-interaction-with-tcolorbox-and-auto) which reports a problem with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[absolute,showboxes]{textpos}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{7cm}(2cm,2cm)Essai\end{textblock*}
\end{document}
```

It might be that there are circumstances where textpos and tcolorbox get confused, or where they *have been* confused in the past.  See @leandris's comment suggesting that this might behave differently with up-to-date package versions.

This isn't a very helpful answer (sorry), but I'm copying here the possible alternative illustration and possible resolution, rather than merely pointing to the bugreport.  That issue list is about to disappear, because bitbucket are deleting Mercurial repositories at the end of this month (June 2020).